# Exception with $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/path/xyz.css'); in Pimcore 5

Tags: php, pimcore

I just created my view.html.php script in Pimcore 5.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to integrate the CSS data. The manual with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static...` is ok.

For example, I used:

```
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css');
```

The file bootstrap.css exists.

Exception:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "headLink" of class "Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader".

Screenshot:
[image]

Can anyone help? Does anyone know next?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using this? Based on your screenshot you are trying to call this inside pimcore/lib/Pimcore/Templating/Helper/Headlink.php which is wrong.

You should use it within view.html.php or layout.html

Comment: Hi, I use my layout.html.php in "/docroot/app/Resources/views" and I can not understand why he is leading me there too. Any idea?